# Is it a good idea to add a WebService Request inside a Custom View?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

So I have lets say I have a requirement where whenever the specific button is pressed, I should call a webservice to send some logs.

This button is present for multiple screens, so I though why not place it inside a CustomView `View` and call the webservice from there?

Then I'll just add this custom view to the xml layout and I don't have to worry about a thing anymore. Is it a good idea?

If it's not can someone suggest a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Please check my suggestion

Comment: Is there any specific architecture that you are currently using?

Comment: @TentenPonce part of the project uses MVP but we are trying to migrate to MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your existing architecture (MVP), it is better to put the logic in the `Presenter`, actually there should not be any logic on the `View` (in your case, custom view) aside from taking input (eg: click of a button), and providing output.

Assuming you set a click listener on your button (well of course):

```
button.setOnClickListener { yourPresenter.doSomeAction() }
```

and in YourPresenter:

```
fun doSomeAction() {
   //do necessary action for the button
   //after that, send logs
}
```

Following these pattern, you can easily make unit tests on your presenter like test if the logs is actually called, (you can also specify exact input).

**Note:** If you're using Clean Architecture, I recommend to put it on the domain layer `(Interactor/UseCase)` as `Presentation Layer` doesn't care what and when to log.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a class let say `RequestSender` that a has string logs as params int the constructor .

And then you will create a method `send()` that trigger the sending process.

And anytime you want to send logs you will proceed as below :

```
RequestSender request = new RequestSender(string logs);
request.send();
```

Comment: I don't really get it. Can you explain further?

Comment: the main idea is to use a class that manage sending logs trough webservices (fucnction send) , it will contain all necessary method to send your request , and then anytime you need to send request , you will create an instance of that classe with your logs as params in the constructor , and then call the method send within your class